# Hibernate Merge Function occasionally gives Primary Key Violation

Tags: java, database, hibernate, merge, indexing

We are using Hibernate in a Java app. To update a certain piece of information (and all its associated dependencies), we are using the Hibernate Merge function:

```
HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();
template.deleteAll(toBeDeletedObjs);
Object mergedObj = template.merge(obj);
```

The main table being updated has 5 columns, the first of which (the PK) is an auto-generated value.

**Occasionally, but not always**, the merge's Insert gives the following error:

[insert into TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)

```
DuplicateKeyException: One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "ID" constrains table "TABLE" from having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=3.53.95
```

I assume the "default" is the auto-generated Hibernate value, so I am not retrieving the previous object's ID; that can't be the cause of the error. Any thoughts on why Hibernate sometimes fails on this merge?

Comment: did you checked the statements that hibernate is trying to execute on the DB? (turn show_sql parameter on)

Comment: Yes, I did; that's how I found out that it was happening on INSERT INTO TABLE. Although I didn't see the actual values being inserted.

Comment: but hibernate must check if it already exists before, isn't there an Select sql just to check if row is there or not? And a bit further, could you paste the SQLs executed by hibernate from the moment merge is triggered?